# Laravel Test seeJsonContains

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, browser-testing

I got this result after running Unit Test.

Result:

```
1) Tests\Functional\Controllers\Api\UsersControllerTest::testUsersIndex
Unable to find JSON fragment
[[{"email":"FRoAff4@mail.com","id":"706"}]]
within
[{"data":[],"draw":0,"error":"Not Found","recordsFiltered":0,"recordsTotal":1}].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Code:

```
$this->seeJsonContains([
  'id'    => $user->id,
  'email' => $user->email,
]);
```

If in parameter I add `true` it works. I do not understand the task parameter is the logical value(true, false) here.

After:

```
$this->seeJsonContains([
  'id'    => $user->id,
  'email' => $user->email,
 ], true);
```

Comment: Thank you for info Remul.
If added ```true```, it will be right?

Answer (score 0):

The second paramater of `seeJsonContains` **negates** the assertion, meaning it will switch from `assertTrue` to `assertFalse`. Thats why your test is passing, because it will instead check that the response JSON does **NOT** contain the `id` and `email`.

To make your test pass make sure your `UsersController@testUsersIndex` returns the correct JSON.

In your case: `[[{"email":"FRoAff4@mail.com","id":"706"}]]`

Comment: If I added ```true```, it does not check. Such email and id (FRoAff4@mail.com","id":"706") exists or not. 
I think this email and ID does not exist.